# Undo svn changesets 1276-1284 and 1286-1294

Tags: svn

Right now I'm at rev 1307. I want to undo the changes of the changesets 1276-1284 and 1286-1294. Basically, it's all the changesets  1276-1294, excluding 1285. I would also like to keep  my latest changes, which are unlikely to conflict with the changes that I want to undo.

Can anybody give me some hints?

Answer (score 3):

In general terms, you can apply a reverse diff for each range you want to undo. For example:

```
svn diff -r1276:1285 > first.patch
```

to create the diff (note the ending version is one revision number *more* than the last one you want to undo), then

```
patch -R < first.patch
```

The `-R` switch tells `patch` to apply the patch in reverse. `svn diff` tells you what you did, so `patch -R` undoes that. You may, of course, have conflicts that you must resolve manually.

Comment: The other answer to the question has "svn merge -r 1294:1285". I used the patch creation described here to solve my question at it worked. Why does this svn diff doesn't have the numbers reversed?

Comment: As Greg says - that's what the `-R` to `patch` is for :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just do a couple of merge commands with the revision numbers reversed. Try this:

```
svn merge -r 1294:1285
svn merge -r 1284:1275
```

I'd recommend you commit your current changes before trying this, or at least create a patch file to back them up.